# How do I write code for solving partial derivatives numerically?

Tags: partial-derivative, matlab

As stated in the title. I am trying to write a function which evaluates the partial derivative at two points (a,b) for f.

However, the output of the partial derivative evaluated at (0,0) is way too large.

My supposition is that my algorithm for calculating the partial derivative is wrong. But I don't see how.

It has been a long time since I've last used MATLAB, so I do apologise if I've made some errors or used a inefficent way of writing my code.

My code is below:

```
function derivative = PartialDeriv(f, a, b, i)

h = 0.0001;
fn=zeros(1,2);

if i == 1
fn(i) = (f(a+h,b)-f(a,b)/h);

elseif i==2
    fn(i) = (f(a,b+h)-f(a,b)/h);
end

derivative = fn(i);

end
```

Calling my function I get:

PartialDeriv(f, a, b, i)

where f is

```
f = @(x,y)(x-1).^2+(y-1).^2
```

I get:

```
f = -1.9998e+04
```

Doing it by hand I should get -2.

The **i** which is seen among the parameters for:

```
 PartialDeriv(f,a,b,i)
```

denotes my index, inorder to distinguish the partial derivative with respect to x and y.

Meaning that fn(1) is the partial derivative with respect to x and 
fn(2) is the partial derivative with respect to y.

Comment: It should be `(f(a+h,b)-f(a,b))/h` not `(f(a+h,b)-f(a,b)/h)`.  You are getting a large value because $f(a,b) / h$ is large (in absolute value).

Comment: (Similar for the $i=2$ case.)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having $f$ accept two arguments, $a, b$, let it accept an argument which is a vector: a_vec = [a1, a2, ..., an].  You seem to need only n=2, but this format will enable you to have the code work for any dimension.

Now:

===========

function derivative = PartialDeriv(f, a_vec, i)

h = 0.0001;

a_dim = length(a_vec)

zero_vector = zeros(1, a_dim)

fn = zero_vector;

for i == 1:a_dim,
  increment_vec = zero_vector
  increment_vec(i) = h

fn(i) = ( f( a_vec + increment_vec ) - f( a_vec ) ) / h;
end

derivative = fn(i);

end

===========

You might want do use double-sided finite differences instead of the above one-sided one:

fn(i) = ( f( a_vec + increment_vec ) - f( a_vec - increment_vec) ) / (2*h);

Comment: Thank you for answering! Since i'm dealing with two input variables, is the method of finite differences necassary to numerically calculate the partial derivatives?

Comment: Depends on how much we know about the algebraic form of $f$ and how simple or complicated that form is.  If it is $f(x) = 3x$, we can easily calculate the exact partial derivatives.  But if it is something complicated or little known, numerical approximation may be the only currently accessible method.